# DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data when trying to replace old array

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I created object and inside this object there is an array (array objects), like so:
[image: pics1].

But in other case i need to add nested array inside this array object. Suppose i want to insert new field in `chapters` index no 0. I want it become like this:

```
-chapters
 - 0 : -chapter: 'Pendahuluan'
       -chapterDesc: 'bla.. bla'
       -id: 59291
       -materi: 
         -0 : title: 'bla..bla'
              desc: 'desc bla.. bla'
         -1 : title: 'bla.. bla again'
            : desc: 'desc bla.. bla.. again'
```

What i did like so;

```
const handleMateri = async (data, index) => {
      showModal.value = false

      const allOldChapter = course.value.chapters
      console.log('old',allOldChapter)

      const newAllChapter = allOldChapter.map(chap => chap.id !== data.id ? chap : data)

      console.log('new',newAllChapter)

      await updateDoc('courses', props.id, { chapters:  newAllChapter})

    }
```

and **Firestore update function**

```
const updateDoc = async(collection, id, updates) => {
        isPending.value = true
        error.value = null

        try{
            let docRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)
            const res = await docRef.update(updates)
            isPending.value = false
            return res

        }catch(err){
            isPending.value = false
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(err.message)

        }

    }
```

then i got this issue

[image: issue]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you can't use a custom object when writing to Firestore.  As far as I can see from your output, your custom object is called "Proxy".  You won't be able to use that.  Instead, you will have to convert that to something that Firestore allows, such as basic JavaScript objects, array, and other basic types.

Comment: could you give me some reference to convert it?